# Was Agni god of death before Yama?

Tags: death, agni, yama

Yama is son of Surya . Who was god of death before Yama ? Was the post held by Agni , I had read about it somewhere that Agni was god of death before Yama.

When was Yama born ?

Comment: Agni is a god of the vedas, the fire god. Yama is the god of death.

Comment: Agni was not a god of death before Yama, but a goddess called Mrityu is the deity of death before Yama.